# Using the self.variable system in a custom module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been writing some code for a controlled assessment (this isn't something that's required before you think I'm cheating... got that's stuff sorted months ago :-P) and I have started to insert some of the functions into modules. I had to do this for some things such as generating a number as I was using it and replicating it so many times I saw no reason to just make it a module.

Anyway, I'm trying to load up a "Save" module and run code within it (Also called "Save") but the issue is that it requires a "Self.[variable]" style variable (it's a listbox used by tkinter if your wondering) and it will not allow me to send the information when I request it to run. it's being triggered by a button and when the button is pressed it is supposed to run the modules code and send to the module a number and the listbox's contents within the variable. any ideas how I can do this?

Code for the button:

```
self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=Save.Save(self, MainFile))
```

Code from module (the majority of it anyway):

```
def Save(self, MainFile):
    a = 0
    with open(MainFile, "w") as savefile:
        savefile.write("\n".join(self.listbox.get(0,END)))
```

(That bit of code doesn't seem to like being posted in the right format sorry :3)
Any help is greatly appreciated...I luckily don't need to think about this for a day or two and if it comes to it I have the weekend...but I have till a week into December to get everything done... :3

Comment: First, separating methods of the same class into different modules is a bad idea. Second, compare the `command` from this line to the `command` values you used [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927327/nameerror-global-name-is-not-defined-creating-error-when-it-has-been-defined). Notice anything different? Perhaps something missing? Think about what you're *supposed* to pass there, and think about what you *are* passing.

Comment: Off-topic: You should follow [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and not name your modules things with starting capital letters. Also, the `command=Save.Save(self, MainFile)` in the `self.fileMenu.add_command()` call is actually calling the `Save.Save()` function right then and assigning its result to the `command` argument.

Comment: Does it trigger an exception, and if so, what traceback are you getting?